# Export all posts as CSV from WordPress DB and open in OpenOffice/Excel

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am exporting all of my posts from phpMyAdmin as a CSV file using , as the column seperator and "" as the text delimeter.

The export works fine but when I open it up in something like OpenOffice, the columns are still broken up where it finds a , in the sentence of either the post or title.

I have been at this for a while now and in the past, and I would like to know if there is a better way to go about this?

At the end of the day, I need to be able to open this CSV file so that I can delete some columns which will not be used and re-imported as products for WP eCommerce. I have another post similar to this, but that did not get me what I want either.

Many thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't have much to do with WordPress. Would probably be better migrated to SO, or perhaps DBA

Comment: No, it's very much got to do with WordPress because I need to be able to import the content back into WP eCommerce. Thanks

Comment: Sure. I understand the source and eventual destination is WP, but it just feels like the actual issue is how to export CSV and then delete columns. Have you tried exporting to tab separated values (TSV) instead - that might solve the issue of commas being recognised as delimiters? I'm pretty sure there's a TSV export plugin

Comment: Thanks Anu. I am going to try pfefferle's idea first and then yours if I don't come right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use a less used character as delimeter for example the "~"? And be sure to add only this character on the import!